# Encoding issue when using Nokogiri replace

Tags: ruby, encoding, character-encoding, nokogiri

I have this code:

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'nokogiri'

s = "<a href='/path/to/file'>Café Verona</a>".encode('UTF-8')
puts "Original string: #{s}"

@doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(s)

links = @doc.css('a')
only_text = 'Café Verona'.encode('UTF-8')
puts "Replacement text: #{only_text}"
links.first.replace(only_text)
puts @doc.to_html
```

However, the output is this:

```
Original string: <a href='/path/to/file'>Café Verona</a>
Replacement text: Café Verona
CafÃ© Verona
```

Why does the text in `@doc` end up with the wrong encoding?

I tried with and without `encode('UTF-8')` or using `Document` instead of `DocumentFragment`, but it's the same problem.

I'm using Nokogiri v1.5.6 with Ruby 1.9.3p194.

Comment: I can't reproduce it using either Ruby 2.0.0 or 1.9.3. What is your Ruby version by the way?

Comment: Have you tried `puts @doc.to_html(:encoding => "UTF-8")`

Comment: @jonallard It's ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0]

Comment: I've tried that @PinnyM but doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems that if you pass a nokogiri text object it does the thing ;)

```
links.first.replace Nokogiri::XML::Text.new(only_text, @doc)
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks. I wonder though why the string directly didn't work. Maybe a bug?

Comment: I seriously doubt it's a bug. 99 out of 100 times it's user error.

Comment: I don't know the interns of nokogiri. So I have no idea if it's a bug. But you can create an issue about it

Answer (score 0):

I can't duplicate the problem, but I have two different things to try:

Instead of using:

```
s = "<a href='/path/to/file'>Café Verona</a>".encode('UTF-8')
```

Try:

```
s = "<a href='/path/to/file'>Café Verona</a>"
```

Your string is already UTF-8 encoded, because of your statement `# encoding: utf-8`. That's why you put that in the script, to tell Ruby the literal string is in UTF-8. It's possible that you're double-encoding it, though I don't think Ruby will -- it should silently ignore the second attempt because it's already UTF-8.

Another thing I wonder about is, output like:

```
CafÃ© Verona
```

is an indicator that the language/character-set encoding of your system and your terminal aren't right. Trying to output UTF-8 strings on a system set to something else can get mismatches in the terminal and/or browser. Windows systems are typically Win-1252, ISO-8859-1 or something similar, not UTF-8. On my Mac OS system I have these environment variables set:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

"[Open iso-8859-1 encoded html with nokogiri messes up accents](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9741023/128421)" might be useful too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I mentioned in my question that I tried both with & without the encode() at the end. And I think my terminal is fine, I'm also on Mac and the other strings appear fine (also UTF-8), so that shouldn't be the problem. Anyway, Ismael's answer fixed my issue but still wonder what was wrong...